# Using flask_excel within Blueprints

Tags: csv, flask

I have an application that is using Blueprints and I need to be able to generate csv files for download. I found the `flask_excel` package which works great, but none of the examples I've found use Blueprints. Here is an example application that works:

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask
import flask_excel as excel

app=Flask(__name__)
excel.init_excel(app)

@app.route("/example", methods=['GET'])
def example():
    return excel.make_response_from_array([[1,2], [3, 4]], "csv", file_name="example_data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, I need something structured like this:

```
#__init__.py
from flask import Flask
import flask_excel as excel

from download_csv import download_csv_bp

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(download_csv_bp)

    excel.init_excel(app)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

and

```
#download_csv.py    
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

download_csv_bp=Blueprint('download_csv',__name__)

@download_csv_bp.route("/example", methods=['GET'])
def example():
    return excel.make_response_from_array([[1,2], [3, 4]], "csv", file_name="example_data")
```

How do I import the `flask_excel` functions that are initialized in `__init__.py`? If I put `import flask_excel as excel` in my `download_csv.py` file, the response generated just prints the resulting text to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than I thought. If I add the line `from app import excel` to `download_csv.py` then it works. My new issue is with ajax calling this route, but as this is unrelated to my original question, I won't ask it here.